# SQLite DELETE query freezes on moveToFirst()

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to delete rows in an SQLite database in an Android application.

Here is the query and the Java code calling it:

```
final Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("DELETE FROM link WHERE version!=? AND sentence IN (SELECT _id FROM sentence WHERE language=?) AND translation IN (SELECT _id FROM sentence WHERE language=?)", new String[]{String.valueOf(versionToConserve), sentenceLanguage, translationLanguage});
cursor.moveToFirst();
cursor.close();
```

**The application freezes on cursor.moveToFirst().**

Here is the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`:

```
selectid:0, order:0, from:0, detail:SEARCH TABLE link USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_link_1 (sentence=? AND translation=?),
selectid:0, order:0, from:0, detail:EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 0,
selectid:0, order:0, from:0, detail:SCAN TABLE sentence,
selectid:0, order:0, from:0, detail:EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1,
selectid:1, order:0, from:0, detail:SCAN TABLE sentence,
```

I thought that maybe the query could be too slow, but after half an hour, it is still stucked here.

I tried to replace `DELETE` by `SELECT`, it freezes as well.

I tried the inner `SELECT` queries alone, they work perfectly.

I tried to replace the inner `SELECT` queries by (1,2,3) and (4,5,6), it works.

I tried to use `JOIN` instead of `IN (SELECT ...)` but it doesn't accept it. It says `LIMIT`, `WHERE` or other terms are expected instead of `JOIN`.

I don't know how to investigate more. Any ideas?

Comment: `DELETE` does not return a result set. Use `execSQL()`, not `rawQuery()`.

Comment: It stays stuck with `execSQL()` too. Why does the Android documentation says "Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE." for `execSQL()`?

Comment: Because the recommended way for deleting rows is the method `delete()`.

Comment: does it freeze when you issue the query with another client as well? then the db might be [corrupted](https://www.databasefilerecovery.com/blog/sqlite-database-corruption.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work with this `WHERE` clause:

```
version<>?
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sentence WHERE language=? AND sentence=_id)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sentence WHERE language=? AND translation=_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `rawQuery()` to delete rows.
The method `rawQuery()` is used to return rows with a `SELECT` statement, in the form of a `Cursor`.

Use [`delete()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)):

```
String strWhere = "version <> ? AND " +
                  "sentence IN (SELECT _id FROM sentence WHERE language = ?) AND " +
                  "translation IN (SELECT _id FROM sentence WHERE language = ?)";
int rows = mDB.delete(
    "link", 
    strWhere, 
    new String[]{String.valueOf(versionToConserve), sentenceLanguage, translationLanguage}
);
```

The returned value of `delete()` which is assigned to the variable `rows` contains the number of deleted rows.

Comment: I did it like that because of the complex where clause. I think it's easier to read. It stays stuck with `delete()` as well.

Comment: Do you have an index for `language` in the table `sentence`?

Comment: No, I don't have.

Comment: You are querying the table `sentence` twice. Create an index: `CREATE INDEX idx_lang ON senetence(language);` and try again.